# CF7 select value get to function and reciept value from function

Tags: functions, customization, select

Si I try to asking different

How I can get the value from following field:

```
<label> Geburtsjahr/ année de naissance (Pflichtfeld)
```

[select* annee include_blank "1940" "1941" "1942" "1943" "1944" "1945" "1946" "1947" "1948" "1949" "1950" "1951" "1952" "1953" "1954" "1955" "1956" "1957" "1958" "1959" "1960" "1961" "1962" "1963" "1964" "1965" "1966" "1967" "1968" "1969" "1970" "1971" "1972" "1973" "1974" "1975" "1976" "1977" "1978" "1979" "1980" "1981" "1982" "1983" "1984" "1985" "1986" "1987" "1988" "1989" "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993" "1994" "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015" "2016" "2017" "2018" "2019" "2020"]

to this function (to which variable? --> myvalues??)

```
function ff_annee_action(element, action)
```

{
switch (action) {
case 'change':

// Catégories Dames

```
    if((ff_getElementByName('sexe').value=='D')&&(ff_getElementByName('annee').value>=1991)&&(ff_getElementByName('annee').value<=2000))
        {
                      var myvalues = ["Damen W20", "Volkslauf Damen", "Walking", "Behinderte Damen"];  //set values as needed
                      mylist   = ff_getElementByName('categorie');
                      mylist.options[0] = new Option('**Kategorie auswählen**', '', true, true);
                      for (var i=0; i < myvalues.length; i++){
                      mylist.options[i+1] = new Option(myvalues[i], myvalues[i]);
                                                             }
                      return;
         }                                                   
        break;
    default:;
} // switch
```

} // ff_annee_action

and how I can return the value from this function to my select Field:

```
<label> Kategorie/ catégorie (Pflichtfeld)
```

[select* categorie id:]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a terrible way to go about population of a CF7 field... However, the way I have done so in the past is to use an identifier as the default value of the field you want to populate, for example {{cf7_year}}.

I would then use a mixture of PHP to query and get the values (if required), and format that result into a string that can in-turn be used in Javascript to replace within the document the term {{cf7_year}} with the string that you have created in PHP, or plain text, or however you're working.

Something a bit like this:

```
var course_email = "<?php echo $email; ?>";

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('{{course_email}}', course_email);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but i am a beginner please explain me step by step.

Comment: where I post this[ {{cf7_year}}]??

[var cf7_year = "<?php echo $year; ?>";]

How is the string for for this  would then use a mixture of PHP to query and get the values (if required), and format that result into a string that can in-turn be used in Javascript to replace within the document the term {{cf7_year}} with the string that you have created in PHP, or plain text, or however you're working

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('{{cf7_year}}', cf7_year);

and where I post this??

Comment: Ok, so in your CF7 Field ( [select* annee include_blank {{cf7_year}}] ) is where you'd insert that new tag. That means that when the form initially loads, its only dropdown selector will be {{cf7_year}}. Then, using PHP, you would compile your string in the format of $dates = '\"1940\" \"1941\"'; etc.Making sure to use backslashes to escape the string to avoid the string from being corrupted. Once you have your string made, you will use the above JS within an on('load') function so as soon as the page loads it will replace the contents of {{cf7_year}} with the string at $dates.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try many thanks and sorry but I'm a beginner

Comment: Sorry for my asking again
when I write like:[select* annee include_blank {{cf7_year}}]  then the field don't show
but when I post like: [select* annee include_blank "{{cf7_year}}"] I can see {{cf7_year}} is that correct??
Next question where I put this string?:[ {{cf7_year}}]?? [var cf7_year = "<?php echo $year; ?>";]